# 48V 300W DC motor e-bike charging or running directly using solar panels. Is it possible?

Tags: transformer, dc-motor, inverter

I have an e-Bike with the system voltage of 48V 300W DC motor. The bike is equipped with AC charger 48V 2A adaptor.
The bike has a lithium battery pack with 48V 11Ah capacity.

So my question is, is it possible to run the ebike directly using solar panel?

Lets say my plan is to use these methods:

Method A:

2 X 12V 50W panels placed on a carrier at the back of the bike, then store the power through PWM controller and a 12V50Ah lead acid battery and then using 500W 24v DC-AC inverter to charge the bike using the adaptor.

Method B:

Directly power the hub (the tire) using solar panel where 2 units of 12V solar panels connected with DC-DC converter to make the output to 48V without having a battery in between.

- Which method is more plausible to be done and most efficient?
- What are the recommended DC-DC converter that is best to step up the voltage?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is method C:

Use your solar panels with an MPPT charging circuit and an output voltage the same as the existing AC charger.  Use that to charge the existing lithium battery.

That's the safest, surest, most efficient way to use solar panels to power your bike.

You'll probably have to let it charge for several hours in the sun.  Bigger panels means a faster charge, but more junk to haul around with you.

---

Method A could work, but the controller on your bike might not play nice with lead acid batteries.  Besides which, lead acid batteries are **heavy.**  You'll have to drag those heavy suckers around even when they are discharged - no fun at all when you have provide all the power through the pedals.

Method B is right out.  Solar panels can only supply as much power as there is in the sunlight falling on them.  That's about [1000 watts per square meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance#Irradiance_on_Earth's_surface) - at noon in the desert.  Everywhere else is less.

Solar panels are maybe 25% efficient.  If you had one square meter of 30% efficient panels, then you could just about deliver full power to your motor from just sunlight - if you could keep the panel in full sunlight, and the wind didn't blow you over.

Comment: the energy from the sun is about 1,000 watts per square meter. The solar panel efficiency will be 10%, 15%, maybe 20%, if the panels are aimed at the sun and maintained at 90 degrees to the sun, and no clouds or trees or buildings create shadows. For 300 watts, with the panels constantly facing straight up, I'd plan on 3 panels of 100 watts each. Thus 1meter by 3 meter surface; a good sun-screen for the rider.

Comment: is there any mppt that i can regulate the DC output voltage and Amperage in the market? any links will be very helpful for that,

and yes, i would go with method C as the most probable and most efficient way. except that i need to cut the adaptor terminal head and connect to the mppt, hopefully there's the same kind of adaptor head in the market. they use the same charger head like most Lenovo Laptop use